# Compile pure x64 dll for C# Webform with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, c++, .net, 64-bit

I'm working with visual studio 2015 and .net 4.5.2 on a Windows 2012 server.  I'm trying to generate a pure x64 dll for a my webforms application.  I've followed the instruction found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4(v=vs.140).aspx

The reason I'm doing this is because I need to call some x64 c++ routines which have been compiled with the /clr switch..  When I attempt to call my c++ routines from testpage.ascx.cs I get:

Could not load file or assembly 'arxTideEngine' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I've used dependency walker to confirm that the dll generated for my webform application is still x86 even though everything else in the dll is x64.

How can I get VS 2015 to generate a pure x64 dll for my webforms application?

Comment: Yes you need to set platform to X64. It is not possible to see what you did wrong - you should check if you have Any/x86 removed from configurations... (Also you really don't need that as long as site runs in x64 app pool)

Comment: This isn't too much I could have done wrong since in order to resolve this issue I've done the following:

Comment: 1) Setup a brand new windows 2012 box 2) Install IIS 8.5  3) Install visual studio 2015  4) Create a new webform application with one test page 5) Set the the platform to x64 as Microsoft recommends.      Is there anything else that need to be done?

Comment: So I created a new application and it now compiles to x64.  Two things that could have been wrong with my first application are 1) I was created before I installed IIS and was running under IIS express or 2) There is a little check box about running the app in azure that I left checked. .

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be related to the fact that the web app was running under IIS  Express.  After creating a new web app that ran under IIS, the x64 compile worded as expected.